# Using the basename of current path to define a new file

Tags: linux, scripting, tcsh

I'm trying to make a script that creates a temporary folder with a particular name, specifically the base name of the folder I'm running the script from. To do this I've tried to do this with the following approach.

```
setenv suffix $(basename $PWD)
mkdir /tmp/userid_$suffix
```

But this fails with an illegal variable name error. I can't seem to figure this out after looking a number of sites and questions on here. How can I add the base name of the current folder to a new folder, either in one step or with setting a variable?

Comment: you know about `mktemp -d` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works a lot better:

```
 setenv suffix `basename $PWD`
```

You indicated /bin/tcsh as your shell.

Comment: Neither csh nor tcsh support `$(...)` style command substitution.  backticks `\`...\`` don't just "work a lot better", they  are **required**.

Answer (score 1):

And since you are in `csh`, it can very simply be written as:

```
mkdir "/tmp/userid_${cwd:t}"
```

wherein from the current dir `$cwd` we can grab it's basename via the `:t` modifier.